# System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatible Exception in MVC 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an ASP.NET Web Application in mvc5 and i made a model class with a controller. My application is running but when i want to access my moviescontroller in url like localhost:1234/Movies it generates an exception in my MoviesController.cs file

The connection string that I'm using is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130819083100.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130819083100;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;User ID=sa; Password=password@123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Function that generating this exception is

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}
```

Edit Exception Details

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Inner Exception Details:

```
    System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenService.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at MvcMovie.Controllers.MoviesController.Index() in d:\Nimit Joshi\Websites\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 20
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
            at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
       InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            HResult=-2146232060
            Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            Class=20
            LineNumber=0
            Number=-1983577832
            Server=""
            State=0
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass2c.<UsingConnection>b__2a()
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 func)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action action)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
            InnerException:
```

My DbContext class is:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public  DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
 }
```

My Whole Configuration File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130819083100.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130819083100;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TempMovies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TempMovies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MvcMovie" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide the exception text if possible.

Comment: @Serv i posted my exception details...you can check it out..

Comment: What Serv meant was provide the inner exception(s) as well, that's where the details are that will guide you towards discovering the problem. Like the message says: Check the inner exceptions for details!

Comment: and which connection are you using? DefaultConnection or MovieDBContext? Are you following a tutorial on www.asp.net? Could be relevant in recreating the problem, if the exception does not give enough information

Comment: @Serv Yes i am following that tutorial, and i am using MovieDBContext as a connection.

Comment: Do you have a reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer in your project? Can you show the whole config - your problem is most likely not with the connection string but how EF is configured.

Comment: @Pawel I posted my whole configuration file..you can check it

Comment: @NimitJoshi: youf config looks fine. I actually missed the error from the database - it contains "error: 50" which I think is a key to solving it. You may want to take a look at the entries in th eventviewer but I also found this: http://rsuharta.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-cannot-create-an-automatic-instance-see-the-windows-application-event-log-for-error-details/ and http://www.aspneter.com/2013/08/error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred/ which hopefully will help you fix the issue.

Comment: @Pawel thanks for reply, but i am not receiving this error. Please check that my exception is EntityFramework.dll is not handled by usercode

Comment: @NimitJoshi I took this from the inner exception you posted above. The problem is that the EF is trying to figure out what version of Sql Server you are running. To do that it tries to connect to the database but it cannot and therefore you get the exception. The message says to check your connection string because it is the most likely reason you are not able to connect to the database but if you carefully look at the most nested exception you will find it (look for  "provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50")

Comment: @Pawel So, sir please tell me What is the solution?

Comment: In the links I pasted above the guy said you need to modify the host.config file and shows it how to change it. I would just try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

please use the correct connection string as provided in the [tutorial:](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model)

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>
```

It is likely a problem with your authentication with the user `sa`.

### //Update

I have just installed VS 2013 on my DevVM (Server 2008R2)
I created an Asp.Net MVC 5 project and used nuget to add Entity Framework to the project.
After this I created the models and added the connectionstring to the web.config
Then I clicked controlles -> add -> scaffold, choose the model data context and name, hit add and then run the project. Works like a charm. All CRUD functionality is working.

Comment: I used this connection string at the very first time in my Web.Config file, but when i got this exception, i changed my connection string and provide user & password.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Comment: please provide your DbContext class in your opening post

Comment: I posted my DbContext class in my opening post

Comment: the same thing i had done but GOD knows what is the real problem?

Comment: a last idea: please check which version of Entity Framework you installed? 5.00 stable or 6.0.0-rc1? I won't have much time today to browse stackoverflow, so my attempts on helping will be sparse

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Preview so EF6 is installed in it by default.

Answer (score 2):

My LocalDB was deleted. I recreate it and my project now is running successfully. Thank you all to support me.

Comment: how can I recreate LocalDB ?

Comment: this is an old question but @Nimit Joshi can you tell me how to recreate LocalDB. I've the same situation as yours

Answer (score 1):

```
> Here EmployeeDetail is a table name and Employee is a model name.  And
> ID,Branch,Salary and UID is a table field


  public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    List<EmployeeDetail> employees = context.EmployeeDetails.ToList();
                    List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
                    foreach(EmployeeDetail item in employees)
                    {
                        emp.Add(new Employee
                            {
                                ID=Convert.ToInt32(item.ID),
                                Branch=item.Branch,`enter code here`
                                Salary=Conve`enter code here`rt.ToInt32(item.Salary),
                                UID = Convert.ToInt32(item.ID),
                            });
                    }
                    return View(emp);
                }



>  view page code


    <div style="font-family:Arial">
        <h2>Index</h2>

        <ul>
            @foreach (var emp in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(emp.Branch, "Details", new { id = emp.ID });
                </li>
            }

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use "." to define the dbserver. use the full machine name

Comment: Please, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by 2 connection strings...had the same problem and getting rid of one helped.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that you may also have some user.config files that have strayed into the path of being picked up by your application

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\PROJECTNAME_vs_Url_a2dblg5lbsfkc1adurpcald1inggdlg1\